# How to use global variables between 2 JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have 2 JavaScript file, and I'm trying to *log* the "global" variable in the 2nd JavaScript file after I assign a value to the variable in the 1st js file. In the first js file I want to open a new window (another .html file) with the variable that's *log*-d

main.js: (1st)

```
var apple;
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function(){
    apple = "apple ";
    console.log(apple ); //log: apple

    window.open("second.html", "_top");
});
```

2nd.js:

```
function test(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(apple); //log: undefined

});
```

Comment: You have two separate _documents_, the global scope doesn't cover multiple documents, every document has its own global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`window.GlobalVar = 'apple'` or `window[DynamicVar] = apple`

If you make an extension, check [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: And Where should I try it: at the 1st or 2nd js file?